# My java application has a very low resolution for some reason

Tags: java, graphics

I ran a program I made a while ago which I never had problems with and it looked very wrong and everything is very... chunky? I guess you would say? It seems like more is wrong than just being pixelated. I ran some of my others programs and they all have the same issue. I have never seen this issue before. I recently got a new computer and this is the first time running my java applications on it. I have anti-aliasing enabled on the Graphics2D object and disabling it only makes it worse.

With anti-aliasing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvNYW.png

Without any RenderingHints: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRAo4.png

Edit: I drawing using a JFrame with a BufferedImage and using the Graphics2D from the BufferedImage.
I found out it was because of high DPI scaling

Comment: Antialiasing should have no effect on BufferedImages, only on Shapes created with the Graphics2D library, and I suspect that you have images of relatively low resolution that is being displayed at a size larger than they should be displayed.

Comment: Even the text is like that though, and I made the images several times bigger than they appear on  the screen and last time I used this it didn't look like this. Every one of my programs looks like this now. If I check the actual pngs I load the button icons from they are fine and they are high resolution. The only images I am using are for the buttons.

Comment: Anti-aliasing *has* an effect on text, but it needs to be the *correct* setting: key:  `RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING` and value: `RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON`

Comment: That only half worked. It's better but it's still pretty bad. I've been using Graphics2D and anti aliasing for a while now and I have never seen this issue until I got my new computer and I think that might be the cause. Could it be something to do with high DPI scaling behavior? I have no idea what it is but it came up earlier when I googled the problem.

Comment: The green bar with the rounded ends also looks like the text does. It's just a rectangle with a circle on each end but the circles have the weird broken chunkiness.